# difference in proportion in multiple sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

[image]

This is the dummy example that I made up. If I want to know whether
the boxer uses different proportions of punch based on opponents, what kind of test should I use. In other words, how can I tell that by different opponents the boxer plays differently?

Comment: Look up Pearson chi-square test of independence.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, your table suggests strategies, but the 'round' numbers would be unusual for real data. You'd need data consisting of counts of punches from boxing matches between boxer A and each of opponents 1 through 5.

These might be as in the fictitious data of the table `TAB` below, sampled in R.  Note that 1=jab, 2=hook, etc.,
the elements of `p` are scaled to add to unity, and wee assume 400 punches per match are randomly sampled. (If there is no proportion
argument in `sample`, then equally likely punches are assumed.)

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = sample(1:4, 400, rep=T, p = 1:4)
x2 = sample(1:4, 400, rep=T)
x3 = sample(1:4, 400, rep=T, p = 1:4)
x4 = sample(1:4, 400, rep=T)
x5 = sample(1:4, 400, rep=T)

t1 = tabulate(x1);  t2 = tabulate(x2)
t3 = tabulate(x3);  t4 = tabulate(x4)
t5 = tabulate(x5)

TAB = cbind(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);  TAB

      t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
[1,]  35  96  36  94  90
[2,]  88 103  68 104 112
[3,] 122 109 118 104  80
[4,] 155  92 178  98 118
```

Then a chi-squared test on `TAB` shows that types of punches
are not homogeneously used against the five opponents.
The P-value is nearly $0,$ so the differences in strategies
against various opponents is significant at any reasonable
significance level.

The observed numbers of punches are shown in `TAB`.
Under the null hypothesis of homogeneity, the expected counts
would be as shown below:

```
 chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)$exp
        t1    t2    t3    t4    t5
[1,]  70.2  70.2  70.2  70.2  70.2
[2,]  95.0  95.0  95.0  95.0  95.0
[3,] 106.6 106.6 106.6 106.6 106.6
[4,] 128.2 128.2 128.2 128.2 128.2
```

The chi-squared statistic is the sum of the squared
Pearson residuals. By looking at residuals with the
largest absolute values, we can see where the major
disagreements between observed and expected counts lie.

```
chisq.test(TAB, cor=F)$res
             t1         t2        t3         t4         t5
[1,] -4.2012073  3.0792940 -4.081855  2.8405890  2.3631791
[2,] -0.7181848  0.8207827 -2.770142  0.9233805  1.7441632
[3,]  1.4915648  0.2324517  1.104145 -0.2518226 -2.5763392
[4,]  2.3669593 -3.1971614  4.398305 -2.6672451 -0.9008576
```

Not surprisingly, they draw attention strategies against opponents 1 and 3 (equally likely punches) and the other three opponents for which left and right upper punches are favored.

It might be interesting to look at a "collapsed" $2 \times 2$ table with two opponent types (1,3) vs (2,4,5) and two types of punches (jabs, hooks) and the other two together.